# First time trying to register and enqueue styles and scripts in Wordpress and can't figure out why it won't work

Tags: php, wordpress, stylesheet

First time trying to register and enqueue styles and scripts in Wordpress and can't figure out why it won't work.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? This is my functions.php file:

```
<?php

function add_theme_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap.min',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap.min-js',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_register_script( 'script',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/script.js');
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-3.1.1',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/jquery-3.1.1.js');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.min-js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-3.1.1' );
    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );

?>
```

and this is my header.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js no-svg">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: pls try by replacing dot(.) by hyphen (-); like `bootstrap.min` to `bootstrap-min`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all!

It turned out to be something very silly... There was a duplicate file-system in my work's FTP... So not code related at all :/

I appreciate the answers though :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with the **handle** `bootstrap.min` you need to change the handle by replacing the .(dot) from it. Please use -(hyphen) instead.

Comment: Don't still people's comments and write them as your own answer. by the way bootstrap comes as `bootstrap.min.js` or `bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Let me tell you that I didnt see the last comment with  the question. I think you didn't read answer too, if you know the wordpress well I am quite particular in my answer. Please read difference between comment and answer in stackoverflow..... Hope you will be more careful in next comments and giving negative marks to others to make them more careful about you...

Comment: I think you dont know what I have written, please read wordpress function wp_enqueue_style and read how to use "handle"....

Comment: WP docs only say that the handle needs to be a unique string. It doesn’t mention any limitations on what characters are allowed, and specifically not that a dot would be a problem.

Comment: Correctly pointed out, that is why I say "I think". I always used in that way and I was trying to help him out in my way only...

Comment: @Tristup there's nothing that say's dot shouldn't be used in handles. handle needs to be a unique string

Comment: @Masivuye, see I have shared my knowledge at my best. I might be wrong or right, let Erin decide it. And you used some abusing words about me...without knowing the answer...if you know the answer...please help Erin  and stop poking me.

Comment: @CBroe, I think as user of stackoverflow I get too many help and also tried to help others..I always keep in mind that to help against the question, nothing else...I think user should have the choice to take or not to take the answer. I really request you as you are a super user to me, please ask Admin to force other user to say causes against the negative and positive marks....

Comment: @Tristup sorry if you felt offended by my comment.

Comment: @Masivuye, Thanks for your sorry...I really like that...I hope all should follow the same gesture... Thanks  again